# How do I pop up a prompt for docker windows container?

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I'm trying to fiddle with the Microsoft containers for docker and am running in to a problem when I want to actually issue commands to my containers. I have done the following to get here:

1. Download and install the **Docker Desktop for Windows** beta (specifically `1.12.3-beta30.1 (8711)`) so that I can "switch to windows containers"
2. Restarted my machine
3. Pulled both the microsoft/nanoserver and microsoft/windowsservercore containers
4. Put docker in path
5. Followed the hyperv steps from here: [Windows Containers on Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10)

Now, when I go to execute `docker run -it microsoft/nanoserver cmd` This is what powershell looks like:
[image: running docker image]

It does the same thing for server core or nano server. It never actually launched a command prompt. It just hangs here and I can't type anything. Here is more info for my images:[image: docker image descroptions]. So, how can I actually begin execution commands on my container?

UPDATE:
I think my actual problem is that I cannot attach to the container. I started over and did the following to figure this out:

1. Delete all existing containers
2. `docker run microsoft/windowsservercore`
3. use `docker ps` to get the container name
4. `docker exec [container_name] cmd`
   powershell shows C:! So the command excuted in the container
5. `docker exec [container_name] ping google.com`
   It pings! hmmm
6. `docker exec -it [container_name] cmd`
   Hangs. No prompt is ever launched.
7. break out of the hanging command
8. Look up what -it does
   I see it part of it is that it attempts to attach
9. `docker attach [container_name]`
   Nothing happens. Powershell just hangs

Comment: Just tried the same thing, though I ran `docker run -it microsoft/nanoserver powershell`, it took a few seconds to start but eventually I got a shell and was able to run a couple of powershell commands to ensure it works.

Comment: Did you do any steps other than the ones in that article I linked? Did that junk stink before "Microsoft Windows" show up for you? Are you using the latest container and beta build?

Comment: I didn't have to put docker into the path, that was done by the installer. Just ran the command I posted and everything worked. As I said, it just took a few seconds to fully kick in. Just as a sanity check, you switched the Docker client over to use Windows containers instead of Linux containers?

Comment: I am in windows client mode.

Comment: Yeah, mine worked out of the box. It's Windows though, maybe another reboot will fix it?

Comment: I believe the problem is that docker can't attach. I've updated my post with my steps.

Answer (score 8):

I've updated to the latest microsoft images as of 12-14-2016 and now everything works find. I can `docker exec -it [machine-name] powershell` and I get a terminal I can interact with!

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with Windows version. You can check your windows version by

**Run -> winver.exe**

You have to update to build no. 14393.576 (latest as of now), this issue will be solved